# Serving a single HTML page from something like Gist or Pastebin

Tags: cdn, gist, pastebin

Are you aware of any service similar to Gist or Pastebin that just serves an HTML page at my own subdomain, as fast as your typical CDN, and can manage <1M requests per day reliably?

....as in nothing else required, just ONE HTML file (which then loads everything else from S3 or something).

I'm also interested in a service that serves one HTML file + manages an associated domain/DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [gist.io](http://gist.io).

You publish a gist in Markdown, then visit it at `http://gist.io/gist-id` in HTML.

Development of gist.io has been ceased for a long time.
It only support the discontinued all digits url syntax of gist.github.com.

[draft.sx](http://draft.sx/) is a fork, and it supports the new url syntax (hex string) of gist.github.com

Comment: Appears to be broken for the longer gist urls.